# R regular expression for data

Tags: r

I have data such as `Data<-("10/11/2021")`.
The only thing I want is to get the digits before 1st slash, digits before 2nd slash and digits after 3rd slash. Please help me do this with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with several `gsub` functions.

```
gsub("/.*$","",Data)
#[1] "10"

gsub(".*/(.*)/.*","\\1",Data)
#[1] "11"

gsub('.*/', '', "10/11/2021")
#[1] "2021"
```

Or you can use `strsplit`.

```
strsplit(Data, "/")
#[[1]]
#[1] "10"   "11"   "2021"
```